# Node app listen on port lower than 1024 on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created an app engine which runs a node application that serves some html, css, and javascript.

I want my node application listen port 443. However my node application gives 503 error if i run it on a port other than 8080

I searched in the web and think that there is a service which accepts clients' requests on port 80(I dont know where the service is running). This service redirects these requests to 8080 port of a virtual machine. And this is the virtual machine that runs my node application.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

So how can i change the configuration of that service to redirect incoming requests to my application on port 443?

Answer (score 4):

Your application **must** [handle requests via port 8080](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listening_to_port_8080). If you're trying to use port 443, I'm guessing you're trying to serve SSL. You can find out more about how to do that in App Engine Flexible (where your Node.js is running) [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#security) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl).

Comment: if i do the things in the links you gave should i use port 443?

Comment: No, you still need to use port 8080 within the container.

Comment: Shoud i use `var https = require("https");` or `var http = require("http");`

Becouse if i use `var https = require("https");` my application still gives 503 error. Although i am listening port 8080.

Is there any resource on the web about this?

Comment: I made a research about using the https module of node js. And i guess the reason why it does not work is that the ssl certificate is for www.mydomain.com but the virtual machine running my code is at some where else. It is a different host. So i cant use my ssl for it. Is there any way to use ssl for my node application?

Comment: You'll need to [follow these steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl). App Engine handles SSL for you, so you should just use HTTP inside your container.

Comment: But there is a problem. It is ok that i can use http inside my webserver node js application. But i am also using a socket server. This socket server runs in a compute engine. And my messages are send through these sockets(socket.io) not http post or get.So i want these sockets to communicate each other securely. I connect my client socket to the compute engine by using its ip(Let say `https://142.124.233.412`) but it gives me an ssl error that say this ssl is not for `https://142.124.233.412`

Comment: Shoud i write a forwarding rule that forwards a port of www.mydomain.com to my compute engine that runs socket server node app? Would it be secure? Becouse i would be using a port other than 443

Comment: @WillHayworth Could you please explain why you insist on using port 8080 within the container? Can't the server listen on any other port even if firewall rules are set to allow them?

Comment: I'm not insisting on anything, I'm describing how the service works. It's not 8080 so much as what the environment sets (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#application_startup), but afaik that's consistently 8080.